# How can i use the method 'registNib' which the flied.xib have two views?

Tags: xcode, xib

[**this is the screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfNAt.png)

1. this controller.xib, i want use the method [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"paycode"],but it not work.
2. when the xib_flied have two views, how can i used the method `registerNib forCellReuseIdentifier`to 
   regeist cells.
3. this is my method:
   `UINib * nibb = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ConfirmChoosePayCodeViewController" bundle:[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"paycode"]];
   [self.tableView registerNib:nibb forCellReuseIdentifier:@"paycode"]`

Answer (score 0):

> when the xib_flied have two views, how can i used the method registerNib forCellReuseIdentifierto regeist cells

You can’t. The only kind of nib you can register as a source of reusable cells is a view nib containing a single UITableViewCell and nothing else.

Comment: thank for your answer. you mean I can't mix UITableViewCell  and otherView in a xibfile。but can creat a xib which have many UITableViewCells?

Comment: No. I mean what I said.